# How to remove decimals in Y Axis in Crystal Reports Chart

Tags: charts, crystal-reports

In my chart I need to show "COUNT" fields for each "GRAPHDATE" (values are shown below):

```
GRAPHDATE   COUNT
2014-01-01  1
2014-01-02  1
2014-01-03  0
2014-01-04  3
2014-01-05  2
2014-01-06  2
2014-01-07  3
```

I managed to do that, but the problem I came across are decimal places in Y axis. I tried formatting the Y axis with decimal places set to 0, also tried this formula to show instead of the COUNT field...

```
ToText({Count Field},0)
```

... as well. But, in my range...

```
0
0,4
0,8
1,2
1,6
2
2,4
2,8
3,2
```

...I have decimals as shown above, so no result. The first option (setting decimal places to 0 does not work) and the second with formula works, but it is not showing the real values because it shows Count of (COUNT Field). I have no option to set Max of (COUNT Field) which is my task (only Count and Distinct Count in Set Summary Operation).

Here is the image preview:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Crystal Report bundles an older version of [CRChart](http://www.threedgraphics.com/tdg/products/tools/crchart/product_info.php) from [Three D Graphics](http://www.threedgraphics.com/).  If you upgrade, you'll have more control over the chart's formatting using [macros](http://www.threedgraphics.com/tdg/products/tools/crchart/html_docs/docs/macros_crce.htm).

Comment: Hi, I was there and downloaded the upgrade and saw that there is a DLL and some examples. I don't actually need that, I just need to set this via CR designer. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @craig I found in "Data (Y) Axis Settings" the "Scales" tab and set there "Major Interval" manually and it works, no decimals anymore. For that DLL... I as I said, I was there and I saw how it works. Thanks, it is very powerful, but I was lucky enough and found this.

Comment: You may want to answer you own question, then mark it as accepted.

Comment: @SidBrooklyn please indicate the version of Crystal Reports you are referring to as there are many and the Chart Options tabs can look different for each. As an example I am having the same issue but am using version XI & Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2012 and the options you present do not appear for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in "Data (Y) Axis Settings" the "Scales" tab and set there "Major Interval" manually and it works, no decimals anymore.